# Angular 12 Unable to load Schema — ng-package.schema.json file inside library

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-packagr, angular12

I did upgrade to angular 12 but I'm not able to build libraries anymore. =
`angular: v12.0.3`, `ng-packagr: 12.0.0`

I'm running the following command `ng build mylib --prod` and get the following error

```
Building Angular Package
ERROR: Debug Failure. False expression.
An unhandled exception occurred: Debug Failure. False expression.
See "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-ql91km\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I then opened the `ng-package.json` file and saw that I had a warning

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  // ...
}
```

```
Unable to load schema from 'c:\Users\myUser\Documents\projects\my-project\my-project-name\node_modules\ng-packagr\ng-package.schema.json': ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\myUser\Documents\projects\my-project\my-project-name\node_modules\ng-packagr\ng-package.schema.json'.
```

I did control and the file does exists. I also did try to reinstall every module but didn't fix it.

I have the following folder structure
[image]

Does somebody face the same problem?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets I'm not sure I remember it correctly, but I do think that this is what I described in my answer. Please let me know if this did helped

Comment: Thanks for the answer, not sure it's our case, but it might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the error was for me the following.

In my ng-pacakge.json I had library that were already enabling, or forcing ivy. But other library weren't. This did create an error, & when running `npm i`, then it weren't downloading every libraries for some reason.

The only way to make it worked again was to remove every library that did forced ivy & put them as `peerDependencies`, or to downgrade them to the correct version that didn't have it yet.